# How to achieve "Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission" in C# azure function

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-functions

My Azure function is developed in C#. I want to execute the Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission or I have to achieve same functionality using C#.

The runtime of Azure function is .net.

I tried to have a look for alternatives but couldnt find any. I am looking for the alternate of     Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission in C#

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking a way to perform the operation, so I found below code.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins-modernize/understanding-rsc-for-msgraph-and-sharepoint-online

and another url below
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/f4e50079f97016ada52c9a43d7d9a41a05c537a9/docs/v4-reference-docs/site-post-permissions.md?plain=1#L31

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).